# argument of \\myMacro has an extra }

Tags: macros, errors

I have the following code

```
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\spec}[2][]{\sigma_{#1}\left(#2\right)}

\newcounter{i}%
\newtoks\striche%
\newcommand{\commu}[2][1]{%
    \setcounter{i}{1}%
    \striche={'}%
    \loop%
    \ifnum\value{i}<#1%
        \striche=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\striche'}%
        \stepcounter{i}%
    \repeat%
    {#2}\the\striche%
}

$\spec[\commu[2]{C}]{x}$
\end{document}
```

I get the error message `argument of \\commu has an extra }`.
Both macros separately are working fine. I figured out that

```
\spec[\commu{C}]{x}
```

does work. So the problem seems to be the optional parameter of `\commu`. Is there any way stack two macros with optional parameters? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the benefit of using `\commu[2]{C}` rather than `C''`?

Comment: That I can change my notation later, if I find a better one.

Comment: Yes, of course. But you can make an intelligent macro too, that lets you write `C''` which is shorter than `\commu[2]{C}`. It was just to note that may be you did not need the macro ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `[]` inside `[]`. To hide this from tex, you can wrap your macro in an additional set of `{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\spec}[2][]{\sigma_{#1}\left(#2\right)}

\newcounter{i}%
\newtoks\striche%
\newcommand{\commu}[2][1]{%
    \setcounter{i}{1}%
    \striche={'}%
    \loop%
    \ifnum\value{i}<#1%
        \striche=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\striche'}%
        \stepcounter{i}%
    \repeat%
    {#2}\the\striche%
}

$\spec[{\commu[2]{C}}]{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or use xparse `\NewDocumentCommand\spec{om}{\sigma\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\left(#2\right)}` and then `\spec[\commu[2]{c}]{x}` and also define `\commu` this way to be sure (with `O{1}` rather than `o` in the argument definition).

Comment: @Manuel I guess showing how to do this with xparse would be an interesting answer on its own. I would certainly upvote, if you would write one!

Answer (score 2):

Typing `\spec[{\commu[2]{C}}]{x}` would solve the problem, but I think you can enjoy a different solution with `xparse`, which allows to take care of some other small issues.

I've made two adjustments: first remove `\left` and `\right` whose only effect is to add unwanted horizontal space before and after the parentheses; second, add the subscript only if present.

There is a difference between no subscript and an empty one; in the latter case TeX adds a horizontal space of size `\scriptspace` (default value is 0.5pt); in the example I make it very large to show what happens. The length 0.5pt is small, but noticeable when present.

The syntax for the definition of `\spec` is that it has an optional argument `o` and a mandatory one. If the optional argument is present in the later input, the condition `\IfValueT` is true and the relative tokens are used (it's a shorthand for `\IfValueTF{_{#1}}{}`, here in the false case we do nothing).

In the definition of `\commu`, the optional argument receives a default value of 1, so it's denoted as `O{1}`.

With `expl3` (on which `xparse` is based) the loop can be greatly simplified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\spec}{om}{%
  \sigma
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}%
  (#2)%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn % we need to access lower level functions; here spaces are ignored

\NewDocumentCommand{\commu}{O{1}m}
 {
  #2\prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { ' }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\spec[\commu[2]{C}]{x}$ % no braces required

\bigskip

% let's show why \IfValueT is necessary
\setlength{\scriptspace}{20pt}

$\spec{x}$

$\sigma_{}(x)$ % what you'd get without the trick

\end{document}
```

Note that no additional braces are necessary here.

[image]

Comment: why is the optional keyword in the case where no default value is set a small`o` and in the other case a big `O`. Moreover why do the default case needs the `m` in brackets?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek The `{m}` was a typo. The difference between `o` and `O{...}` is that in the first case you can test the presence of the optional argument with `\IfValueTF`; in the second case, the absence of the optional argument means `...` is used.